# Azure Cognitive Search Pass Or IaaS

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a basic query on **Azure Cognitive search** -I have confusion that, **will it comes under PaaS or SaaS** service? With my understanding I feel it should be PaaS, since it requires configuration and deployment involved. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Cognitive Search is a PaaS service. While there is a portal experience to help configure and evaluate the service, you need to write your own application to call the service in order to use its functionality.

Comment: Yes, I feel its PaaS service, but I am looking is there any **reliable source of reference** to say it is **PaaS** service.

Comment: I have worked on the service since 2013. I think I’m a pretty reliable reference. 

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cognitive Search is a **search-as-a-service**.

**Search as a service** uses a **software as a service (SaaS)** model.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_as_a_service

Comment: Customers of Azure Cognitive Search have to write code to use it, so I would argue our service is PaaS, not SaaS. Same for search-as-a-service in general.

Comment: I have similar opinion as @BruceJohnston

Answer (score 0):

As a Customer of Azure cognitive search, I had to code all back-end services that can handle creating of data sources, indexers and indexes and also the same for calling the rest API to get the data, so even if it is possible to do it via the portal azure interface we still need to code to get some advanced features not yet presents in the interface.
So I believe it is a PAAS cloud type.